# update in snowflake table, if values not updated then set to 0

Tags: join, sql-update, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to update a table in snowflake with the results of a join. t1 looks like this

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 0 |
| 3 | c | 1 |

table 2 looks like this they are matched on col1 a unique identifier

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 |

I want to update col3 with the result of the join, if there is no match then 0 if there are a match then update to 1. so in this example we can see there isn't a join on value 3 in col1 so that should be updated to 0.

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 1 |
| 2 | b | 1 |
| 3 | c | 0 |

I've tried with the following solution but, as it stands it is being updated to null.

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET col3 = IFF(t2.col2 IS NOT NULL,1,0)
FROM (SELECT col1, col2 FROM t2)
WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: 2 has a match, why the col3 output for that col1 value is still 0? I was expecting `(2,b,1)` instead of `(2,b,0)` while following your reasoning.

Comment: Following on from @lemon's comment, are you trying to set values to 1/0 depending on whether there is a match or are you trying to update the values in T1 to what is in T2.Col2 when there is a match and set it to 0 if there isn't a match?

Comment: sorry my mistake, I have updated. trying to set values dependent on whether there is a match. I think I may need to do the join in the subquery but feel like thats inefficient

Comment: Try with `UPDATE table1 t1 SET col3 = IFF(t2.col2 IS NOT NULL, 1, 0) FROM t2 WHERE t1.col1 = t2.col1 (+)`.

Comment: this does work but I notice the documentation advises against using this for newly developed code.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what % of the table is being updated when you execute this query?  Are you updating 1's and 0's on a lot of records every time this is executed?  If so, perhaps an `INSERT OVERWRITE` into t1 from t1 left join to t2, with a case statement would be easier.  It would also allow you to sort the table on 1 and 0, if that is how the table is queried (avoid having to auto-cluster the table).